# Input validation in cshtml (MVC 4) without using the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, validation, razor

I'm looking for a way to validate the input of a form (name, email, price, etc.) on a cshtml page.
I've searched the internet and every tutorial uses model to validate the input.
Is there another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well with model class its a lot easier to validate a form in MVC if you are not using model classes for some reason then you have to use jquery plugins for form validation here are good plugins links.

http://formvalidator.net/

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement client side validation you can try AngularJs.
[Angular JS Form Validation guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)